# passing 2d array in c using pointer to pointer by typecasting

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

[How to pass a 2D array as a parameter in C?](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-2d-array-parameter-c/)

I was searching to pass a 2d array to a function in c and I came across the above site. I understood the first and second way of passing 2d array, but I got 
confused in the 3rd method, specifically, how is it even working that way?`

```
3) Using an array of pointers or double pointer
In this method also, we must typecast the 2D array when passing to function.
    #include <stdio.h>
    // Same as "void print(int **arr, int m, int n)"
    void print(int *arr[], int m, int n)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
    }

    int main()
    {
        int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        int m = 3;
        int n = 3;
        print((int **)arr, m, n);
        return 0;
    }
    Output:

    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`

The above code works fine on codeblocks.
When calling **print()** from main(), we pass **arr** as argument by typecasting it to pointer to pointer , but in the function **print()** it dereferences only once to print the values. `printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));`
Shouldn't it be `*((*arr+i*n) + j));`, I tried compiling this statement , it compiles but doesn't execute.

```
2) Using a single pointer
In this method, we must typecast the 2D array when passing to function.

#include <stdio.h>
void print(int *arr, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *((arr+i*n) + j));
}

int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print((int *)arr, m, n);
    return 0;
}
Output:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`

The 2nd method and the 3rd method only differ in the type of argument passed in the **print()** function while rest of the code is same. So what is actually the difference between the working of the functions?

Comment: Both examples are horribly incorrect in the fact that they interpret an object as an different incompatible object. This causes undefined behavior. There is not point reasoning what they do, rather find a correct example.

Comment: @2501 But why do they give the correct output? What do you mean when you say "object as an different incompatible object"?

Comment: The [C FAQ reference](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html) at the end of the Geeks-for-Geeks article says (at the end): _Finally, we might explicitly note that if we pass a multidimensional array to a function [...] we can not declare that function as accepting a pointer-to-pointer_. The comments in the article also point out that the 3rd method is wrong.

Comment: 3 cannot work because it demands a pointer array without providing one. 2 works because of similarities between real two-dimensional arrays and single-dimensional ones.

Comment: The variable `int arr[][3]` infact occupies a contiguous area of memory, for which arr points to its beginning. That is why single dereferencing works. As if your two dimensional array is single dimensional just like you wrote in  `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}`

Comment: @Medinoc I also thought that 3rd method will not work, but when i compiled and executed, it is giving the correct output. Why?

Comment: Apparently, because it doesn't actually use its argument as the pointer array it demands. More precisely, it doesn't attempt to dereference the "pointers" in the array, it merely displays them. With the `%d` format specifier. In short, a whole bunch of wrongs end up making a right.. on this one architecture. It could fail on a 64-bit non-ILP64 platform.

Comment: @Selçuk But in the 3rd method, you are passing a typecasted arr into the print function (typecasted into pointer to pointer), so that must use double dereferencing. Your explanation is valid in case 2, but I don't understand how is it in case 3.

Answer (score -2):

easiest way to pass 2D array,

function

```
void PrintArray(unsigned char mat[][4]){
    int i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(j = 0;j<4;j++)
                printf("%3x",mat[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

main

```
int main(){

int i,j;
//static int c=175;
unsigned char  state[4][4], key[4][4], expandedKey[176];


printf("enter the value to be decrypted");
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        scanf("%x",(unsigned int *)&state[j][i]);
PrintArray(state);

return 0;
}
```